# Manually upload or install BREW files on the phone

Tags: testing, brew-framework

I have quite rare Kyocera phone as a gift. A limited number of that phones was special developed for my local mobile operator for testing-only purposes back in 2006. It is based on MSM6500 and doesn't have any webbrowser BREW applications in it. I wonder if I could upload any locally compiled BREW files in it i.e. example .mif/.bar files from BREW SDK 2.1? I have digged the file system using QPST EFS Explorer. Can I copy *.bar files directly to the phone? How to install brew application to the local phone, if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://hacktherazr.com/qa/how-do-i-side-load-brew-app-verizon-v3m discusses the question on a verizon Brew equipped phone.